# Apply mask and compute statistics with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, masking

I've constructed a VRT that includes a band of data and a mask (0/1 representing water/land) with:

```
ds = gdal.Translate(masked_vrt, combined_vrt, bandList=[1], maskBand=2, format='VRT')
```

Where combined VRT has band 1 of data and band 2 of 0/1.

I would like to use the python GDAL bindings with this VRT to compute the statistics of the data after applying the mask but `ds=gdal.Open('masked.vrt').GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(0,1)`
gives only the stats of the original, maskless, data (band 1).

I can get the result I'm looking for like this:

```
ds = gdal.Open('masked.vrt')
data = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
mask = ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetMaskBand().ReadAsArray()
masked_data = data[mask>0].mean()
```

But reading in the arrays of course loses the efficiency of using the VRT.

**Is there some way to use GDAL directly to apply the mask and compute the stats?**

Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
data1 = np.ones([5, 5]) * 2
data2 = np.ones([5, 5]) * 5
mask1 = np.zeros([5, 5])
mask2 = np.ones([5, 5])
data  = np.vstack([data1, data2])
mask  = np.vstack([mask1, mask2])

## dummy geotransform
gt = [-78.38, 2.7e-04, 0, 37.33, 0, -2.7e-04]

data_ds = gdal_array.OpenArray(data)
data_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

mask_ds = gdal_array.OpenArray(mask)
mask_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

## write datasets
gdal.Translate('data', data_ds, outputType=gdal.GDT_Float64)
gdal.BuildVRT('data.vrt', 'data')
gdal.Translate('mask', mask_ds, outputType=gdal.GDT_Float64)
gdal.BuildVRT('mask.vrt', 'mask')
gdal.BuildVRT('combined.vrt', ['data.vrt', 'mask.vrt'], separate=True)

ds = gdal.Translate('applied_mask.vrt', 'combined.vrt', bandList=[1], maskBand=2, format='VRT')
ds1 = gdal.Open('data.vrt', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
print ('Original Statistics:', ds1.GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(0, 1))
print ('Masked Statistics:', ds.GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(0,1))
ds = None; ds1 = None
```

If working, original and masked would differ, of course.

Comment: Maybe reading http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc15_nodatabitmask gives some ideas.

Comment: Thanks I'm familiar with these sites but they provided no new information.

Comment: Does gdalinfo -hist take the mask band into account?

Comment: Nope, it does not @user30184; should I edit the OP to include a copy of the vrt?

Comment: A test case that could be reproduced at home could be useful indeed.